# How to GET response of next 3 days weather forecast using openweathermap API

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I am using the "OpenWeatherMap" API to get the weather forecast. I get a response for the current day weather. But I am not getting how to get a result for the next three days weather forecast with a date.

Here is mine current code Json:

```
override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            try {
                /* Extracting JSON returns from the API */
                val jsonObj = JSONObject(result)
                val main = jsonObj.getJSONObject("main")
                val sys = jsonObj.getJSONObject("sys")

                val updatedAt:Long = jsonObj.getLong("dt")
                val updatedAtText = "Updated at: "+ SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH).format(Date(updatedAt*1000))
                val temp = main.getString("temp")+"°C"
                val tempMin = "Min Temp: " + main.getString("temp_min")+"°C"
                val tempMax = "Max Temp: " + main.getString("temp_max")+"°C"
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you are using current weather data API to fetch the data, it will return only current day data. You can get forecast data for 4 days or for 7 days using the below APIs:

[Hourly Forecast for 4 days](https://openweathermap.org/api/hourly-forecast)

[Daily Forecast for 7 days](https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-api)

Process the JSON at the android end to get 3 days of data only.

Answer (score 0):

Use Postman to check your link first.
[image]

In Android Studio, use the plugin to convert JSON to an entity.
[image]

I will use retrofit to get list of the data. I only remembered to use AsyncTask on the first week of school. Later, I always use Retrofit to treat API because it saves a lot of work. Here is the gradle dependencies for Retrofit:

```
// Retrofit
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$gson_version"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$converter_version"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttp_version"
```

In MVVM, the data request from Repository => API service => ViewModel => Activity/Fragment.